# Best way to blur jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have been developing a page where I open up a set of tools and everything underneath is blurred except the tool icons that are overlaid. ( Like mac's Launcher app )

Here is the how I've done it:

HTML

```
<body> 
    <div id="tools"></div>
    <div Id="Blur">in here I have all my page content</div>
</body>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){ $('Blur').blur(); });
```

The thing is: this works, but the problem is once there is a decent bit of content on the page the blur is really slow to transition in and out. Does anyone know of a better way to blur a page without it taking a large hit to performance?

( If formatting doesn't look good or you need more information just tell me! This is my first post with Stack Overflow )

Thanks!

Comment: are you using some library to create the blur effect?  jQuery blur is the onblur event handler.  Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: Judging by your incorrect selector, the lack of citing any plugins/libraries, and my doubts that any plugin worth its name would overwrite the existing `blur()` function, something is certainly amiss in your example. That in mind, you can use CSS for that - Jack A has an example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use a [CSS blur filter](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-filter-effects-blur-grayscale-brightness-and-more-in-css/#blur) for that.

```
#Blur {
    filter: blur(1px);
}
```

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/1duss393/

Comment: So I redid my code with your example. Here is my jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/edogLdy2/1/

Problem is, when there is a lot of content on the page the transition is slow or laggy. Is there a way to blur a lot of content without the lag when using transition?

Comment: @IsaacS.Weaver Using CSS for effects normally has the best performance since it's implemented by the browser. I don't know any tricks to optimize the CSS approach, but you may be able to find some tricks if you search for that.

Comment: Thanks @JackA. I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery blur() function doesn't mean exactly blurring something.
It is function which will work when user will for example click outside element or click tab key.
It's the same as focus() but "reverse".

So if you have input in your html, and you want function which will work when user focuses on input (click() is not the same because user can focuses on input with tab key) then you will use:

```
$("input").focus(){...};
```

But if you want function which will work when user unfocus from input (click outside or press tab key or change chrome tab - whatever)  then you will use:

`$("input").blur(){...};`